# Getting around naming conventions on inputs?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a set of inputs that I'm using jQuery validate on, and they all base their 'error-logs' off of their names.

This wouldn't be a problem, except most of the names are set to fit with our DB so they can be uploaded on submit.

For example, I have these naming rules right now, which work great for 'first name' and 'email'

```
rules: {    
    firstname: {
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
    }
},
messages: {
    firstname: "Please enter your name",
    email: "A valid email is required",
}
```

But whenever I have a name like this input:

```
<input id="edit-submitted-constituent-base-total-constituents" class="form-text hs-input" name="submitted[constituent_base][total_constituents] total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="">
```

It gets a little tricky because it won't register `submitted[constituent_base][total_constituents] total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database` as a name and let me change the error.

My only two thoughts were to add a `name=""` onto the input, which doesn't work, and then somehow trying to figure out how to call to it by an `id` or some sort. Has anyone accomplished this?

Comment: Would [this article](http://johnnycode.com/2014/03/27/using-jquery-validate-plugin-html5-data-attribute-rules/) be of help?

Comment: Just tested on JSFiddle, looks alright, will move to my project, but there shouldn't be any reason why it wouldn't work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The title is not really accurate.  You don't need to get around anything.  If the `name` contains special characters, you surround it with quotes as explained in [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)) and Barmar's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put quotes around property names in Javascript object literals when the name is not a valid identifier:

```
rules: {
    "submitted[constituent_base][total_constituents] total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database": {
        required: true
    }
},
messages: {
    "submitted[constituent_base][total_constituents] total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database": "You have to fill in this field"
}
```

Note that `jquery-validate` automatically detects the `required` attribute in the `<input>` element, so you can leave that out of the rules and just use this for the messages.